# Can I limit Mustache to the current scope?

Tags: mustache

Is there a way in [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) to refer to the current scope only?

```
{
  "name": "name1",
  "list": [
    {
      "name": "name2",
      "value": 200
    },
    {
      "value": 300
    }
  ]
}
```

Output:

- name2: 200
- name1: 300

Since it searches ancestor scopes.
But what I need is:

- name2: 200
- 300

Is there a way to avoid namespace collision like this?
I don't want to set `"name": ""` in the object where name should be empty, since it's created dynamically.

Comment: I wish there was something like `{{[name]}}` where "[ ]" would limit the search to the current scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to do what you're looking for in spec-compliant Mustache. That doesn't mean it's not possible, however :)

A few ways to do it:

- There's [a proposed spec extension](https://github.com/mustache/spec/issues/52) — sometimes called "anchored dot notation" — that would let you write `{{ .name }}` … it's basically a combination of the implicit iterator, `{{ . }}`, which refers to the current section context, and dot notation, `{{ foo.name }}`. Note that it hasn't been added to many Mustache implementations, so this might not work for you, depending on your flavor.
- If your Mustache library implements any of [the proposed filters specs](https://github.com/mustache/spec/issues/41), you might be able to use that to prevent checking parent section contexts. The viability of this answer depends a lot on your language. In Ruby you can do it with a proxy that implements `#method_missing`. In PHP, you can do the same with `__isset` and `__get`... [Here's an example of that in PHP](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/pull/129#issuecomment-13025193).
- But really, the simplest answer is to just always specify a `name` property in your child objects. If there's a `name` and it's an empty string, the parent context won't even be checked.